# Redirect one domain to another on same server using Apache

Tags: apache, redirect, configuration, server, multiple-domains

I have two domains, example.se and example.com, which I'd both like to point to the same server and just presenting different language translations when viewing the site. I'm running Apache and PHP and have set up a default page that takes a GET argument then sets the content to show in either language.
How would I configure this with Apache so that if the user types example.se, he/she would end up with example.com/?lang=se instead, while keeping the .se domain in the url? There's just one page on the site so no need to worry about routing.

Comment: You can use rewrite conditions in a .htaccess file, but is using PHP an option?

Comment: Okay. Not sure how I would go about to do that, but you'd say that is the preferred method?

Comment: I don't know which one is "best", but it's definitely an option that may be easier for beginners to implement.